# Linux Mint LiveCD showing very strange display

Tags: linux, display

I just don't know how to describe this and it's been keeping me from properly Googling...

This is what I see when I boot to the Linux Mint 32-bit LiveCD from a DVD using a DVI video connection using an older PCI graphics card on a machine a friend gave me through a KVM (I don't *think* the KVM is the problem though):

[image: Boot screen]

How can I make my screen appear more... Normal?

*edit* the same thing seems to happen with Ubuntu.

Comment: That looks like the "Zesty Zebra" edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by installing Ubuntu LTS (instead of the leading build) and installing without updating.

Then I manually ran the update tool and unchecked everything related to graphics and Unity; I suspect the Unity updates are what caused the problem but I didn't feel like installing again just to find out.